# SendGrid SMTP API for Applying Template

Tags: php, json, email, templates, sendgrid

I'm trying to apply the sendgrid templates by building the SendGrid X-SMTPAPI headers in my index.php.

This is an abstract of my index.php code:

```
            // Start Sendgrid
            $sendgrid = new SendGrid('userid', 'pwd');
            $header = new Smtpapi\Header();
            $filter = array(
              'templates' => array(
                'settings' => array(
                  'enabled' => 1,
                  'template_id' => 'f2c99ace-87af-2618-8390-c19e2ad2805f'
                )
              )
            );
            $header->setFilters($filter);
            $emailwelcome    = new SendGrid\Email();
            $emailwelcome->addTo($email)->
                   setFrom('hello@world.com')->
                   setFromName('Welcome to World')->
                   setSubject('Your Invitation')->
                   setText('Hello World!')->
                   setHtml('<strong>Hello World!</strong>');
            $sendgrid->send($emailwelcome);
```

To apply the templates, as copied from the SendGrid documentation:

*"Enabling a Template
To use a Template Engine template when you send, enable the templates filter and set the template_id to one of your Template Engine templates.*

Example

```
{
  "filters": {
    "templates": {
      "settings": {
        "enable": 1,
        "template_id": "5997fcf6-2b9f-484d-acd5-7e9a99f0dc1f"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*You can use this JSON in the X-SMTPAPI header of an SMTP message, or in the x-smtpapi parameter of a mail.send API call."*

Question is... **where is the X-SMTPAPI header of my SMTP message?** In my composer.json or index.php or in the vendor files?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it helps at all, there are templating services that work on top of SendGrid, such as sendwithus.com or customer.io. Might be worth checking out depending on your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so apparently. All you need to do is add these 2 lines of code in the index.php:

```
addFilter('templates', 'enable', 1)->
addFilter('templates', 'template_id', 'f2c99ace-87af-3618-8390-c19e2ad2805f');
```

Weeeeeeeee~