# Sendgrid X-SMTP-API returns error when using EnableTemplateEngine

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sendgrid

I'm actually using ASP .NET Core 1.1.

project.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "SendGrid.NetCore": "1.0.0-rtm-00002",
    "Sendgrid": "8.0.5"
}
```

Code used to send email:

```
public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string content)
{
    var message = new SendGridMessage();
    message.AddTo(email);
    message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("geeks@test.io", "test");
    message.Subject = subject;
    message.EnableTemplateEngine("18d89b42-d094-49fb-86c4-5f5821a2eb67");
    message.Html = "test";
    message.Text = "test";

    var credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
        _emailSettings.Username,
        _emailSettings.Password
    );

    var transportWeb = new SendGrid.Web(credentials);
    return transportWeb.DeliverAsync(message);
}
```

I'm unable to send email when I try to use template [`message.EnableTemplateEngine("18d89b42-d094-49fb-86c4-5f5821a2eb67")`]. However, any email sent without template is working as expected.

I also tried this instead of EnableTemplateEngine in reference to [SendGrid SMTP API for Applying Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763303/sendgrid-smtp-api-for-applying-template):

```
message.Header.AddFilterSetting("templates", new List<string>() { "template_id" }, "18d89b42-d094-49fb-86c4-5f5821a2eb67");
message.Header.AddFilterSetting("templates", new List<string>() { "enable" }, "1");
```

I receive this error:

```
JSON in x-smtpapi could not be parsed
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I do not use the class "SendGridMessage".

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/USE_CASES.md